# How to union two tables with Orderby clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables - table1 and table2. Both contains two columns - rollnum,name. Now I wants to select all rows from table1 and randomly 5rows from table2. I have written like this

```
select rollnum,name from table1 union (select top 5 rollnum,name from table2 order by NEWID())
```

but it shows  an error `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.` please help . I think the mistake is at NEWID(). here rollnum is primary key

Comment: why do you want use NEWID() in your query?.
your usage of NEWID is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the brackets. Try this instead

```
 select rollnum,name from table1 
 union 
 select * from (select top 5 rollnum,name from table2 order by NEWID())  t
```

If you could have duplicate entries you may want to consider a `union all` instead of `union`

Comment: @podiluska  yes it's cool !! but can you please explain what the purpose of this 't' ?? thankyou

Comment: 't'.. its just an alias.You may use select t.rollnum,t.name as well

Answer (score -1):

Try This..

```
SELECT  rollnum AS 'NewID' ,
        name
FROM    table1
UNION
SELECT TOP 5
       rollnum ,
       name
FROM    table2
ORDER BY NewID
```

NEWID() is a function which assign a value to a variable declared as the uniqueidentifier data type

Comment: Doesn't do what the OP requested?

Comment: @Prashant16 I have tried this.It doesn't generate any error. But the contents on table2 is not getting randomised.